# Checksums are calculated after the form validation: how to notify the users of an error

Tags: django

Django 1.11.6

I'm developing a document archive. So, I calculate checksums to control that documents are still present, that they are not corrupt etc.

Another side of this is that I can control whether a file has already been uploaded. It is important: no need to duplicate the files.

I upload files through Django admin. There is a form prepared.
But the problem is: form validators seems to be not very useful here.
At least I can't invent how to use a form validator here.

But post_save signal are useful: here we have a file already uploaded. We calculate the checksum of the file (using md5).

But if unique=True for the checksum, IntegrityError is risen.

It is Ok and predictable. But could you help me understand how to notify the user about this? Any method would suffice. It is just for our staff: no need to organize a brilliant html layout. But what is important is to show that the uploaded file coincides with an existing file with the following id.

**Could you help me with this?**

**models.py**

```
class FileChecksum(models.Model):

    checksum = models.CharField(blank=True,
                                null=False,
                                unique=True,
                                max_length=255,
                                verbose_name=_("checksum"))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.checksum



class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(blank=False,
                                   verbose_name=_("Image"),
                                   max_length=255,
                                   upload_to=get_sheet_path)

    file_checksum = models.OneToOneField(FileChecksum,
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)

    @property
    def checksum(self):
        pass    

    @checksum.setter
    def checksum(self, new_checksum):
        pass
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Image)
def save_file_checksum(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    new_checksum = get_checksum(instance.file.path)
    instance.checksum = new_checksum
```

**admin.py**

```
class ImageForm(FileMixin,
                ModelForm):
    model = Image


class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ImageForm

admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

Comment: Probably you can try with email notifications?

Comment: Sometimes it takes several minutes to deliver an email. Well, delays happen. And minutes may sum up into hours. And there is no guarantee for the delivery of emails at all. And isn't it clumsy? Users may not like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to calculate it *before* you save. That way your form can benefit from it and form validation will take care of bubbling up the error to the user. Decouple the `get_checksum` function away from the signals and calculate it as part of the form validation.

I had the same situation where I had a non-trivial hash calculation. So as soon as all the other basic validation stuff was done, I calculated the has with a function and if it clashed, made it part of the form (invariants) validation. If it didn't clash, it got used in about-to-be-created instance.

But I also, made it so that if you try to create an instance of the model, but don't have a hash set, a `pre_save` signal would create it. Useful for code paths where the item isn't coming in from a regular form.